# Random points representation

Tags: functions

*Let's start with the following disclaimer: Math Noob Asking the question.*

I have a set of 30 (to be assumed) random numbers (they're actually not random at all): `91,99,104,114,40,120,41,102,111,114,32,120,32,105,110,32,114,97,110,103,101,40,51,50,44,49,50,54,41,93`

They're the ASCII values of this python code `[chr(x)for x in range(32,126)]`

After mapping each number to incremental values on the `x` axis, I would get the following graph:

[image: Plotted Points]

Is it possible, to build an function that will output this exact sequence of numbers? In other words I'm looking for a way to describe these numbers, or regenerate them, while maintaining all their properties, without enumerating them one by one. How feasible is this?!

***Edit:***
*I'm interested in this specific set of numbers only.*

Comment: What would be the end goal of this function?  Wouldn't the list you have satisfy all of your needs already?

Comment: If I have a way to develop functions for any given, similar, set, and if these functions are smaller (in terms of number of character/size (bytes) needed to represent it on a machine) I would have managed to compress the code. I will use these functions to generate the set and have the machine execute the translated code.

Comment: Technically, the list of numbers is already a function (a function of the numbers 1 through 30).  A list of 30 numbers is hardly worth compressing.  Any other way of getting them would surely take up much more space.

Comment: @BassemDy on your graph I see a maximum of a little less than 90. There are 2 such points. Where are the 120 and 114 and some others like 110?

Comment: @bobbym Oh my apologies, I attached the wrong graph. This one is for the set where each number is reduced by 32. I updated the question.

Comment: @mathematician Except for the fact that this list of 30 numbers, contains more information than the numbers themselves. This list is to be translated into executable code. Now regarding other ways of getting them consuming more space, you are correct, a polinomial function of order 22 is not an option. I was hoping for other methods maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure there exist a function $f(x)$ that goes trough these points, for $x=1,2,...,30$. But searching such a function will be tough. A polinomial of this form would be relatively easy to find, but in this example the polinomial has to be of a minimal order $n=22$. So even if it will give you your desired better compression (wich I strongly doubt), the time to construct such a function will take just to much effort.